# JSlider value only showing upon moving slider

Tags: java, swing, jslider, changelistener

So im using a JSlider to display rain amount in mm,but the rain amount pops up once I move the slider,I want it to be present before I move the slider.
Here are the code segments from my program.

```
    slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0 ,100,0);
    slider.setBounds(70, 70,120,35);
    int sliderValue = slider.getValue();
    event e = new event();
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setBounds(120, 200, 100, 300);


public  class event implements ChangeListener{ // For Slider

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

        int SliderValue = slider.getValue();

        label3.setText("Rain ammount: "+SliderValue+"mm");

    }
}
```

Comment: You can probably just create your `label3` as `label3 = new JLabel("Rain ammount: 0mm");`

Comment: What about the slider value?

Comment: Initially, the slider value is 0. So the text on the label will have to be `Rain ammount: 0mm`. When you change the slider (so that its value is no longer 0), then the label will be updated anyhow.

Comment: then rain amount just dissapears and it is replaced with the slider value..

Comment: Nevermind working now thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not entirely clear what the last problem was, here the answer from the comments, in order to give this question the chance to be moved out of the "unanswered" list:

You can probably just create your `label3` as

```
label3 = new JLabel("Rain ammount: 0mm");
```

Initially, the slider value is 0. So the text on the label will have to be `"Rain ammount: 0mm"`. When you change the slider (so that its value is no longer 0), then the label will be updated anyhow.